# armv 7 has no pc-rel bx thumb instruction in ObjectiveC Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, armv7

I get the following error when integrating a (.a) library into my iOS project:

> ld: armv7 has no pc-rel bx thumb instruction. Can't fix up branch to
>   NO BINDING in _cvGetTickCount in '_cvGetTickCount' from
>   /Volumes/work/project/ThirdParties/Lib/mylib.a(cxswitcher.o)
>   for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The library was built with armv7 for iOS 8.1 and the project's build is with armv7 for iOS 8.1 also, xcode version 8.

I don't have any clue regarding this issue and didn't found a solution. What seem to be the problem here? Any hint will help. Thanks